# Odd cURL timeout behaviour

Tags: php, curl

I have a cURL functionality that has started to timeout suddenly when it tries to connect a third party service.
I am a bit lost what could be the issue as nothing has changed (what I know of). Here are what I have tried:

- Run cURL on other two servers to rule out blacklisting. Those servers
  have same settings, different IP and they have not done cURL calls to
  the service before. Still timing out.
- Check our other cURL functionalities to make sure it is not the cURL library. Those work ok so happy days.
- Ran same code on local machine to make sure if the settings is the issue. That worked ok.

So from above I have concluded it is something in those three servers' settings that are not working correctly. However, my knowledge on cURL server settings stuff is a bit lacking which is why I am here.

BTW, the third party service does not require whitelisting so that cannot be that either.

I have also tried putting the cURL timeout to minutes and that did not work either.

The third party service provides SSL and non-SSL connection and I have tried connecting to both without success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It sounds to me as the 3rd party server is having issues of its own.

Comment: I was assuming same too but when I ran the cURL on my local machine (different IP from our servers), it worked fine every time.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that one. Have you inspected the outgoing traffic with wireshark? With it you can possibly spot if there is a difference in the requests between local and remote requests. Also, you can try to tunnel your request from your local machine through your server via a SOCKS proxy or an ssh tunnel to make absolutely sure the timeout is not caused by which block your IP address is in.

Comment: I will try that! Thank you.